# How to connect SQL Server CE 3.5 to Crystal Report in VB.net 2010

Tags: sql-server-ce, crystal-reports-2010

It's possible to connect sql ce 3.5 to crystal report. I've tried to create new connection in database export (crystal report) but can't find Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 connection.
Also try to add SQL Server CE's .sdf files, still can not. any help please.

Comment: See  this link http://jasonirwin.ca/2009/04/05/crystal-reports-and-sql-server-ce/

Comment: Check this question. I asked it for C#. But you easily convert it to VB.net.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830404/how-to-connect-sql-compact-edition-database-to-crystal-report-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the way to do it straight forward aswell, the way I did it, I connected .sdf file to DataGridView and then thrue DataSet connect to Cristal Report.
Try this if it will help you
http://www.setha.info/ict-vb2008/41-ict-vb2008-0009.html