# Crystal report does not show any data from local .sdf database in c# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010, report-viewer2010, local-database

I have created a windows form application and added a local database on it and a crystal report and a crystal report viewer. here is the code

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {           
        CrystalReport2 rpt = new CrystalReport2();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from cus_info", conn);
        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        report r = new report();
        da.Fill(ds, "cus_info");
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        ShowDialog();
        //crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
    }
```

but crystal report shows nothing after debuging the program.

Comment: Try putting it in `Form_Load` event

Comment: I did it by a Button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830404/how-to-connect-sql-server-compact-edition-database-to-crystal-report-in-c-sharp