# trying to bind Crystal Reports and View in Run time C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

```
private void PrintPreview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (GlobalVariable.GlobGetRowID > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                BindingData();                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
        }
    }
    private void BindingData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(GlobalVariable.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string QueryBuild = "SELECT TravelOrderNo, RowDate, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, PositionDesignation, OfficialStation, Destination, " +
                    "Purpose, DtOfDeparture, DtOfReturn, MeansOfTransportation, Fare, PerDiam, Others1, Others2, RemarksAndRecommendation, " +
                    "RecommendedBy, ApprovedBy, IntRow FROM TravelOrderTable Where IntRow = @param1";
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(QueryBuild, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = GlobalVariable.GlobGetRowID;
                    SqlCeDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(read);

                    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
                    ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

                    GlobalVariable.GetRptPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Reports"];

                    rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\TravelReport.rpt");
                    rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
    }
```

What I've Done:

I created a Crystal Report place it at "\bin\debug\Reports\TravelReport.rpt"
I also click the option Choose a Crystal Reports in the Crystal Report Viewer option and Bind the Crystal Reports Path

On The Crystal Reports I Have Provide its Database Expert at My Connections Selected the Dataset1 which in my dataset1 i have created a TravelOrderTableAdapter

my Question is how can i make my codes right to make my crystal report viewer display the data i wanted to view based on my c# form paramater IntRow ID.

Please Help any who has experience this already im using local compact database just to let you know.

Comment: Not sure, but try calling RefreshReport after setting the ReportSource

Comment: it's showing a pop up asking for a database login why is it? i haven't set any database password and username i place the data in a dataset.

Comment: Can't you add the credentials to the connection string? Where does this occur while debugging?

Comment: after the rpt.setdatasource(ds).. This Error Appear: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is the dll actually there?

Comment: if it's ok sir can you give me just a quick things to do to create a crystal reports binding using compact database? sqlceserver style and ado.net dataset like how to i bind them by just passing the paramater and what should i be doing for the crystal viewer to setup..

Comment: i really have follow and tried ways just to simply bind a crystal report and my compact database with a table name travel order by passing a RowID as a parameter retrives the specific row and display it by report

Comment: Well the exception sounds like SAP Crystal Reports isn't installed. Without it the project might build but wont execute. Please verify if Crystal Reports is installed on the machine.

Comment: SAP Crystal Reports has been installed sir. if i try running the report without data on it just plain report with the design no data it runs smoothly and displays the report the only problem is that when i start trying to add data for the report it then starts to have some of this problems. which is i think it's the binding i maybe have mistakenly coded.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating a DataSet to populate the fields in the report? Try settings just the FirstName for example.

Comment: do you have a simple step by step tutorial on how to bind a c#.net compact database sql and crystal report for a stand alone system without sql server..?? that's what im trying to do and when i do it it's asking for a database login, which i don't have one because im using compact database

Comment: Would this article help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830404/how-to-connect-sql-server-compact-edition-database-to-crystal-report-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

This Is the code:-

```
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = @"C:\WorldSalesReport.rpt";
```

I am not a pro programmer but I also stoked with same problem in my software you need mention the  location of "Report.rpt"

for this you can use

```
 exestr = (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

which will give you the application (nm.exe) location "C:/nm.exe"

```
 int exelen = exestr.Length;
 exestr = exestr.Remove(exelen - 6, 6) + "Report.rpt";
```

In this I am removing the nm.exe from string .Then It will be "C:/" after I added the Report.rpt

Then you need only:-

```
   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = exestr;
```

Refer :- https://help.sap.com/viewer/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/SP21/en-US/45b0c03b6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html