# How to View Crystal report in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I'm working on ASP.Net with C#, and installed CrystalReport 13 for Visual Studio 2013. I wrote code to fill a `Datasource` and pass it into my `CrystalReport file, but my website doesn't show anything. How can I execute my report?

Here is my PageLoad:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
command.Connection = cnn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "STP_T00050030";
command.Parameters.Add("@F_CNTRowID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32("20");
command.Parameters.Add("@F_CNTid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32("45");
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(ds);

ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report1.rpt"));
crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```

Comment: maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830889/2263683

Comment: Thanks Alex ,but in my project seems everythings is OK , and i trace the code , and done success , but nothing shown in browser about crystalreport.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your solution, right mouse click on each report (.rpt file) and go properties --> Build Action=Content, Copy To Output Directory=Copy Always
2. Here's a complete block of code for setting data source. Notice how data source must also be set for each subreport.

   ```
   public static CrystalReportSource Crystal_SetDataSource(string reportName, object par1, object par2, object par3)
   {
       CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource2 = new CrystalReportSource();

       CrystalReportSource2.CacheDuration = 10;

       CrystalReportSource2.Report.FileName = @"~\App_Pages\Secure\Reports\" + reportName;

       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase = CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.Database;
       ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
       crConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
       crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = db;
       crConnectionInfo.UserID = crystalUser;
       crConnectionInfo.Password = pwd;
       crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;


       // First we assign the connection to all tables in the main report
       TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
       foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crDatabase.Tables)
       {
           crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
           crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
           crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
       }


       //SET DATASOURCE FOR EACH SUBREPORT IN REPORT
       foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section section in CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections)
       {
           // In each section we need to loop through all the reporting objects
           foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject reportObject in section.ReportObjects)
           {
               if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
               {
                   SubreportObject subReport = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                   ReportDocument subDocument = subReport.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName);

                   foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in subDocument.Database.Tables)
                   {
                       // Cache the logon info block
                       TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;

                       // Set the connection
                       logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;

                       // Apply the connection to the table!
                       table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
                   }
               }
           }
       }


       if (CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Count > 0)
           CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(server, db, crystalUser, pwd);

       CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(crystalUser, pwd, server, db);
       if (par1 != null)
           CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, par1);

       if (par2 != null)
           CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, par2);

       if (par3 != null)
           CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(2, par3);

       return CrystalReportSource2;
   }
   ```

Comment: Properties does not have 
Build Action=Content, Copy To Output Directory=Copy Always. Only has File Name and Full Path