# Visual Studio 2013 Crystal report error "MIssing parameters Values"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am working on an application, which comes from several migrations. It started in Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Report 9 and is now in Visual 2013.

The latest version of the code was lost and I am recovering a backup.

I installed in my local PC Crystal version 13.0.26 for 32 and 64 bits, where I can edit the reports from both Visual Studio 12 and 13, and also run the reports from designer.

this is what I installed

[image: Installed Dlls]

All reports are simple, and receive a parameter to perform a Select to the database.
The paremeter is called @ID

The problem I have is that, when I run it from both Visual give me the message 'Missing Parameter Values.'

First I thought it was a problem with the version in which the reports were created, but I created a new report and the same thing happens. Even the reports created in this version of Crystal do not receive the parameters.

I think the problem is how the parameters are passed. I think the way to pass it was changed from version 9 to 13. This is what I have configured in Web.Config and on the page that calls it.

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </assemblies>
```

this is my aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="REPVisitasDiariasTecnicos.aspx.cs" Inherits="REPVisitasDiariasTecnicos" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CR" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <div>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer" runat="server" 
        AutoDataBind="true" 
        EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" 
        ToolPanelView="None" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" 
        DisplayStatusbar="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" 
        HasDrillUpButton="False" HasGotoPageButton="False" HasZoomFactorList="False" 
        />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

and this is my code behind.

```
 private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
    {
        oReport = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath;
        reportPath = Server.MapPath(@"report.rpt");

        oReport.FileName = reportPath;
        // establish the connection

        string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WEB"].ConnectionString;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder SConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString);

        // establish the connection with the report
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo() { ServerName = SConn.DataSource, DatabaseName = SConn.InitialCatalog, UserID = SConn.UserID, Password = SConn.Password };
        CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = oReport;
  
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table t in oReport.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo boTableLogOnInfo = t.LogOnInfo;
            boTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            t.ApplyLogOnInfo(boTableLogOnInfo);
        }
    
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
       //Add the parameter to a Lisst
        arrayList.Add(31302);
   
        ParameterFields parameterFields= CrystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo;
        SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(parameterFields, arrayList);
    }

    private static void SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(ParameterFields  parameterFields, ArrayList arrayList)
    {
        ParameterValues currentParameterValues = new ParameterValues();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (object submittedValue in arrayList)
        {
            ParameterDiscreteValue paramValor = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            ParameterField param = parameterFields[i];

            paramValor.Value = submittedValue.ToString();
            param.CurrentValues.Add(paramValor);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I read a lot in this blogs, I have no subreports, no linked values.. Just the ID.

I know there are many things to take into account when changing versions.

I can't think of anything else I can set.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Since the error is the most important clue you have, does it give you a stack trace and line number(s)? If so start there and work backwards. I'd also consider pausing and going through all the code to gain a thorough understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

reading this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283619/how-to-view-crystal-report-in-visual-studio-2013)

I replace this function, where I setting the parameters

```
SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(parameterFields, arrayList);
```

for this line

```
oReport.SetParameterValue(0, 24234);
```

there parameters are passing using `SetParameter` in this version oy Crystal Report